# Floating position of a cone in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The following question arose during a DnD-session...

How would a cone made of ice with a height and diameter of 15 feet float in salt water, specifically in which position? The debate is currently if it would swim with the tip upwards, the bottom (flat side) upwards or if it would lay on its side.

We found only the following text (only in German), but it does not conclude an answer:
http://gymnasium-wk.de/sites/default/files/mathematik/Eintauchtiefe-Kegel.pdf

Also sorry if the tag does not fit...

Comment: First step: where is the center of mass for such a cone?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the problem of floating-body stability. The stability of a floating body in a certain orientation basically depends on the relative positions of the center of mass and center of buoyancy in said orientation.

I found [this](https://www.eng.uwo.ca/people/esavory/STABILITY%20OF%20FLOATING%20BODIES.pdf) text on the web, which you might find useful to solve your problem. You'll need to apply the stability-checking procedure outlined in the text for the two positions of the cone, and see which one is stable and which is not.